Docker registry scope missing in bearer token
I would like to programmatically inspect some images on docker hub. I found some guidance at https://distribution.github.io/distribution/spec/auth/token/
I request a token like below. Looks a bit like OAuth2 Resource Owner Password Credentials flow:
curl -X GET --basic --user myself "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:postgres:pull"
# Enter host password for user 'myself':

Response:
{
    "token":"eyJhbGciOiJS...",
    "access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJS...",
    "expires_in":300,
    "issued_at":"2024-10-12T19:13:38.347643413Z"
}

The token payload is
{
  "access": [],
  "aud": "registry.docker.io",
  "exp": 1728760718,
  "https://auth.docker.io": {
    "plan_name": "free",
    "username": "myself"
  },
  "iat": 1728760418,
  "iss": "auth.docker.io",
  "jti": "dckr_jti_gMe1SEuZOCWZTiagjx-U6zyLclw=",
  "nbf": 1728760118,
  "sub": "55b2b442-41ab-498b-843d-40d87a8593a2"
}

But it does not authorize me to use the API. I think it should look like this:
{
  "access": [
    {
      "type": "repository",
      "name": "postgres",
      "actions": [
        "pull"
      ]
    }
  ],
  ...
}

What is going wrong? I have tried using a Personal Access Token (PAT) instead of my account password but it makes no difference.

Via https://github.com/distribution/distribution/issues/1203 I found that the name should be library/postgres instead of postgres.
With such a token it is possible to do more requests like
curl --oauth2-bearer eyJhbGciO... \
  -X GET \
  https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/postgres/tags/list

